# How to wrap body text around image for drupal 8

Tags: media

How to wrap body text around image for drupal 8. I found tutorial for drupal 7 here https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2008-06-30/how-to-wrap-body-text-around-image, but I still confused to implement this for drupal 8.

I found some css files inside css folder and which one that I have to edit?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't edit css files in a contrib theme, because the changes will be overwritten when updating the theme. Create a subtheme and add a library with your own css file, see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/creating-a-drupal-8-sub-theme-or-sub-theme-of-sub-theme

Comment: Any other simple tutorial?, I just want to wrap body text around image